# How to setup new ConsentDebugSettings.Builder().addTestDeviceHashedId("DEVICE_ID")?

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, admob

I always used the following implementaion for testing Ads within my app:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this)
val testDeviceIds = listOf(
    "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
     ....

     "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
)
val configuration = RequestConfiguration
    .Builder()
    .setTestDeviceIds(testDeviceIds)
    .build()
MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(configuration)
```

Recently I noticed new suggestion in the logs:

```
Use new ConsentDebugSettings.Builder().addTestDeviceHashedId("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX") to set this as a debug device.
```

and I added that to the code:

```
ConsentDebugSettings.Builder(this)
            .addTestDeviceHashedId("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX").build()
```

But no result, it keeps showing that message again and again.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ConsentDebugSettings like this:

```
private ConsentInformation consentInformation;
private ConsentForm consentForm;

private void showConsentForm() {
    ConsentDebugSettings debugSettings = new ConsentDebugSettings.Builder(this)
            .setDebugGeography(ConsentDebugSettings.DebugGeography.DEBUG_GEOGRAPHY_EEA)
            .addTestDeviceHashedId("your_device_id_from_logcat")
            .build();

    ConsentRequestParameters params = new ConsentRequestParameters
            .Builder()
            .setConsentDebugSettings(debugSettings)
            .setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(false)
            .build();

    consentInformation = UserMessagingPlatform.getConsentInformation(this);
    consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(this, params,
            new ConsentInformation.OnConsentInfoUpdateSuccessListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConsentInfoUpdateSuccess() {
                    if (consentInformation.isConsentFormAvailable()) {
                        loadForm();
                    }
                }
            },
            new ConsentInformation.OnConsentInfoUpdateFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConsentInfoUpdateFailure(FormError formError) {
                }
            });
}

private void loadForm() {
    UserMessagingPlatform.loadConsentForm(this,
            new UserMessagingPlatform.OnConsentFormLoadSuccessListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConsentFormLoadSuccess(ConsentForm consentForm) {
                    this.consentForm = consentForm;
                    if (consentInformation.getConsentStatus() == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.REQUIRED) {
                        consentForm.show(this,
                                new ConsentForm.OnConsentFormDismissedListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onConsentFormDismissed(@Nullable FormError formError) {
                                        // Handle dismissal by reloading form.
                                        loadForm();
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }
            },
            new UserMessagingPlatform.OnConsentFormLoadFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConsentFormLoadFailure(FormError formError) {
                    /// Handle Error.
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, what I should do with params?

Comment: First you have to setup GDPR with your google admob account with fill up form,

Comment: then if you test this implementation then first install Europe VPN and then install sign apk, the Google GDPR form is getting popup.

Comment: Make sure during creating sign apk comment that ConsentDebugSettings  part

Comment: Now see my answer, i edited with full code

Comment: Accept answer if it's working

Comment: Thank you so much for your efort. In case of creating sign apk, I should comment `ConsentDebugSettings` and also I should commet `.setConsentDebugSettings(debugSettings)`, right?

Comment: yes, then after if you want to test apk, then you have to install Europe VPN app and then install that sign build.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I think, if you are in Europe, you don't need any VPN app, to test the app.

Comment: Yes Corrects, no need to use VPN..